# Setting a bottom constraint to a UITextView if needed

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uitextview

I'm trying to fix an issue with a UItextview which I placed at the bottom of a viewcontroller programmatically and sometimes it can clip through the bottom of the view if I don't set a constraint like so.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfyPi.png

Whenever I try to constraint the textview to the bottom of the safe area, the text needlessly expands too much if there's less text.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w1v2.png

Here's the relevant code snippets from the textview and the constraints respectively:

```
   private let summaryTextView: UITextView = {
    
    let summaryTextView = UITextView()
    summaryTextView.textColor = .label
    summaryTextView.backgroundColor = .customWhite
    summaryTextView.textAlignment = .center
    summaryTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
    summaryTextView.clipsToBounds = true
    summaryTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    summaryTextView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    summaryTextView.isSelectable = false
    summaryTextView.isEditable = false
    summaryTextView.isScrollEnabled = false
    summaryTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return summaryTextView
}()

private func setupConstraints() {
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
        imageContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 120),
        imageContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
        imageContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 280),
        imageContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.4),
        
        summaryTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainerView.bottomAnchor,constant: 15),
        summaryTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant: 10),
        summaryTextView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant: -10),
        summaryTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
    ])
    backgroundImage.fillSuperView(to: view)
    bookCover.fillSuperView(to: imageContainerView)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the height constraint for UITextView(). Because you are giving fixed top anchor and and bottom anchor so it stretches the textview.